# How to account for interval-censored data in Kaplan-Meier analysis in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, survival-analysis

I have insects that got progressively colder in a cooling bath and were removed one at a time at temperatures ranging from 0 to -35. I made the column `removal_temp` the absolute value of removal temperature. This way it can function how time normally would in survival models. I checked if they were alive or dead (there were no repeated measured, each insect checked once at just one temperature because we kill them in ATP stain to find out if they...were alive. They're sessile so it has to be this way). If they were alive (`death = 0`), that would be right-censored data. If they were dead (`death = 1`), that would be interval-censored data, because they could've died at any sub-zero temperature, not necessarily right when they were checked. I thought I found out how to account for both types of censoring here:

```
surv_object_interval <- with(insect_data, Surv(start_temp, removal_temp, event = death)) 
surv_object_interval
```

the format of the survival object is `(0, 35+]`; intervals! However, when I produce results and a plot:

```
km_interval <- survfit(surv_object_interval ~ 1)
summary(km_interval)

ggsurvfit(km_interval) +
 labs(x = "Removal Temperature (-°C)", y = "Survival Probability") +
 add_confidence_interval()
```

They are identical to the following, where I don't include `start_temp`,

```
surv_object_original <- Surv(insect_data$removal_temp, insect_data$death) 
surv_object_original 
km_original <- survfit(surv_object_original ~ 1) 
summary(km_original)

ggsurvfit(km_original) +
 labs(x = "Removal Temperature (-°C)", y = "Survival Probability") +
 add_confidence_interval()
```

How could this be? It can't be that interval censoring is the default, because, if so, how would it know the other boundary of the interval (0)? It must be that I am not getting R to understand my data's censoring. How do I get R to understand that where `death = 1` it is interval-censored, and where `death = 0` it is right-censored? I have scoured the internet and cannot find anyone who has had this problem. I know there are other packages, other ways, but I've tried to no avail. It must be possible...right?

Here are the packages used and sample data to reproduce the problem:

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)

#data sample
set.seed(1738)
n <- 40
removal_temp <- seq(10, 35, length.out = n)
start_temp <- rep(0, n)
death <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0) 
insect_data <- data.frame(removal_temp, start_temp, death)
```

Comment: The results will be the same because no additional information is provided by the interval start.  All intervals begin at 0, and it's effectively time-to-event again.

Comment: you need to specify `Surv(..., type = 'interval')`

Comment: @SmokeyShakers I would expect the curve to shift left though, as I'm indicating that they could have died at a higher temp (earlier, if you're thinking in classic survival stats). I looked into the interval package and did this `fit<-icfit(Surv(left, right, type = "interval2")~Collection, data = LLTemp)
plot(fit)` and it looks a bit different but there is no way to find quantiles and confidence intervals